# Newby q: what is the backbone of a script to limit incoming and outgoing network speed, using TC?

Tags: traffic-shaping

I am new to `TC` / `tc` (traffic control), but I need to limit the speed of incoming/outgoing network traffic for a docker container.

I read a lot, but still I have a lot of confusion on what is needed.

Some post mention that **egress** and **ingress** speeds must be limited separately, some don't..

Some posts use `htb`, some `tbf` ...

Can someone state the backbone of setting these limits, using TC?

- How should I order the classes?
- What are the steps that I should take
  care of?
- What is the best type of qdisc to use?